# CollisionBitMask

Tags: swift, spritekit

Нигде не могу найти ответ, прописываю взаимодействия между объектами:

```html
Player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
Player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Border | PhysicsCategory.All | PhysicsCategory.Bod1
```

В collisionBitMask у меня очень много объектов, я пытаюсь заменить эти строчки одной переменной:

```html
mask = PhysicsCategory.Border | PhysicsCategory.All | PhysicsCategory.Bod1
Player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = mask
```

какого типа должна быть переменная mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во-первых, в языке Swift можно писать без явного указания типа, ибо тип итак выводится автоматически на основании контекста, например так:

```
let mask = PhysicsCategory.Border | PhysicsCategory.All | PhysicsCategory.Bod1
Player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = mask
```

А во-вторых, член-данное `categoryBitMask` класса `SKPhysicsBody` идее тип `UInt32`, поэтому можете указывать данный тип и явно:

```
let mask: UInt32 = PhysicsCategory.Border | PhysicsCategory.All | PhysicsCategory.Bod1
Player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = mask
```